# How to Deallocate memory from an object in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to figure out how to release the space occupied by a python object while working on jupyter notebooks.

In the specific scenario, i am working on multiple large dataframes and once I have finished doing some computations, i would like to load up a new dataframe.

However this always causes a memory error and my system starts freezing up.

So i figured I will try deleting the python object.

Things i have tried so far :
1. Using del and invoking garbage collector

```
del pyobject
import gc
gc.collect()
```

2. Using ipython magic commands

   %reset_selective -f *pyobject*

Both these approaches fail to actually release the memory. Looking at the htop command shows me that still 20GB of my RAM is being used up by the jupyter notebook. They memory is only deallocated when i restart the kernel (but then i end up losing all the other variables i require for my next stage of data analysis)

Comment: A bit off topic, but my opinion is that ipython is great for demos and experimentation. Once serious data processing is needed, export the data processing to regular functions in a python module.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that no other references exist to your data. Are there no other views based on that array? You can get the objects that hold a reference to something using [get_referrers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers)

If there are any views you should promote those to copies. 
In particular ipython tends to keep references to previous evaluations in variables named `_, _1, _23 etc`. %reset_selective should clear these though.

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend using** **`%xdel var_name`** instead of `del var_name` or `%reset_selective -f var_name`. It works better because it deletes not only variable but also all (or almost all) the references to it.
From IPython documentation:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-xdel

> **%xdel** Delete a variable, trying to clear it from anywhere that
> IPython’s machinery has references to it. By default, this uses the
> identity of the named object in the user namespace to remove
> references held under other names. The object is also removed from the
> output history.
>
> Options
> -n : Delete the specified name from all namespaces, without checking their identity.

From my attempts to find out how memory freeing works in IPython notebooks i learned that `del var_name` and `%reset_selective -f var_name` actually deallocates memory (which can be seen in Windows Task Manager) only if you create an object (dataframex) and delete it never outputting it. If you do output it by typing `df` in the next cell to see what it looks like or by doing something like `df.head()`, `df.values`, then `del` and `reset_selective` will only delete the reference to the object but memory will remain occupied. This happens because IPython stores cell outputs in variables like `_`, `_1`, `_15` (number indicating cell run order), which apparently refer to object and don't allow to deallocate the memory.

So to actually release the memory you should delete the variable that has stored the output of your dataframe. To do that call function `globals()`, which returns all variables from current namespace, find the name of variable that stores object output and delete it using `%xdel`, for example `%xdel _3`. If you did output your dataframe multiple times, then `%xdel` all the _variables containting those outputs/views.

Note that if you try to delete those _variables with `del` instead of  `%xdel` then it won't work and the only option will be to restart the kernel.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

big_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12_000_000, 15)) # ~1400 megabytes
```

```
big_df.head() # outputting dataframe
```

```
%xdel big_df 
# would release the memory instantly if outputted whole dataframe (typed 'big_df' 
# instead of 'big_df.head()' in the previous cell)
```

```
globals() # looking for variable that stores the output (in our case should be _2)
```

```
%xdel _2 
# after deleting output variable(s) the memory should finally be released

# don't use 'del _2'. Memory won't be released and you won't be able 
# to release it without restarting the kernel. (At least I don't know a way)
```