Why is my code leaking memory despite using Garbage Collector?
We are creating the Music-Genres Classification ML model for college final year project. We are trying to extract features from Sound using Librosa. This is the code We wrote. But This code is leaking memory somewhere. I even used the garbage collector to manually collect the garbage in the function call before going down the call stack. I don't understand the part where it's leaking the memory.
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import librosa
import librosa.display
import soundfile as sf
from glob import glob
from itertools import cycle
import random
import gc
import queue

# Seaborn visualization setup
sns.set_theme(style="white", palette=None)
color_pal = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"]
color_cycle = cycle(plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"])

# %%
# Path to the nested folder structure
# audio_files = glob('genres_original/**/*.wav')
# print(audio_files)

audio_files = list()
subdirectories = os.listdir("./genres_original")
for subdirectory in subdirectories:
    subdirectoryPath = os.path.join("./genres_original",subdirectory)
    if os.path.isdir(subdirectoryPath):
        files = os.listdir(subdirectoryPath)
        selected_files = random.sample(files,1)
        full_path_selected_files = [os.path.join(subdirectoryPath,wav_file) for wav_file in selected_files]
        audio_files.extend(full_path_selected_files)
print(audio_files[:10])

# Output directories for saving plots and MFCC features
output_dir = 'output'
spectrogram_dir = os.path.join(output_dir, 'spectrogram_plots')
mel_spectrogram_dir = os.path.join(output_dir, 'mel_spectrogram_plots')
mfcc_dir = os.path.join(output_dir, 'mfcc_features')
os.makedirs(spectrogram_dir, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(mel_spectrogram_dir, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(mfcc_dir, exist_ok=True)

# %%
# Function to augment audio
def augment_audio(y):
    y_pitch_shifted = librosa.effects.pitch_shift(y, sr=22050, n_steps=4)  # Assuming default sr
    y_time_stretched = librosa.effects.time_stretch(y=y, rate=1.5)
    noise = np.random.randn(len(y))
    y_noisy = y + 0.005 * noise
    listReturn = [y_pitch_shifted, y_time_stretched, y_noisy]
    return listReturn

# %%
def plotSTFT(y, sr, file_basename, suffix):
    # Compute and save STFT spectrogram plot
    D = librosa.stft(y)
    S_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(D), ref=np.max)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))  # Reduced figure size
    img = librosa.display.specshow(S_db, x_axis='time', y_axis='log', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'Spectrogram Waveform of {file_basename}{suffix}', fontsize=14)
    fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format='%0.2f')
    spectrogram_filename = os.path.join(spectrogram_dir, f'{file_basename}{suffix}.png')
    plt.savefig(spectrogram_filename)
    plt.close(fig)
    del fig,spectrogram_filename,D,S_db,ax,img
    gc.collect()

# %%
def plotMelSpectrogram(y, sr, file_basename, suffix):
    # Compute and save Mel spectrogram plot
    S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, n_mels=128)
    S_db_mel = librosa.amplitude_to_db(S, ref=np.max)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))  # Reduced figure size
    img = librosa.display.specshow(S_db_mel, x_axis='time', y_axis='log', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'Mel Spectrogram Waveform of {file_basename}{suffix}', fontsize=14)
    fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format='%0.2f')
    mel_spectrogram_filename = os.path.join(mel_spectrogram_dir, f'{file_basename}{suffix}.png')
    plt.savefig(mel_spectrogram_filename)
    plt.close(fig)
    del fig,mel_spectrogram_filename,S,S_db_mel,ax,img
    gc.collect()

# %%
def computeMFCC(y, sr, file_basename, suffix):
    # Compute and save MFCC features
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=13)
    mfcc_filename = os.path.join(mfcc_dir, f'{file_basename}{suffix}.csv')
    mfcc_df = pd.DataFrame(mfccs)
    mfcc_df.to_csv(mfcc_filename, index=False)
    del mfccs, mfcc_filename, mfcc_df
    gc.collect()

# %%
# Function to process a single audio file
def process_audio_file(y, sr, file_basename, augment_index=None):
    suffix = f'aug{augment_index}' if augment_index is not None else ''
    plotSTFT(y, sr, file_basename, suffix)
    plotMelSpectrogram(y, sr, file_basename, suffix)
    computeMFCC(y, sr, file_basename, suffix)
    gc.collect()

# %%
def doStuff(wav_file):
    file_basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(wav_file))[0]
    # Load the audio file
    y, sr = librosa.load(wav_file)
    
    # Process the original audio file
    process_audio_file(y, sr, file_basename)
    # Augment the audio and process augmented versions
    augmented_audios = augment_audio(y)
    for i, aug_y in enumerate(augmented_audios):
        augmented_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{file_basename}aug{i}.wav')
        sf.write(augmented_filename, aug_y, sr)  # Save the augmented audio file
        process_audio_file(aug_y, sr, file_basename, augment_index=i)
        os.remove(augmented_filename)
    del augmented_audios, y, sr, file_basename
    gc.collect()

# %%

fileQueue = queue.Queue()
for wav_file in audio_files:
    fileQueue.put(wav_file)

while not fileQueue.empty():
    wav_file = fileQueue.get()
    doStuff(wav_file)
    gc.collect()


I originally written code VS Code with Jupyter Notebook extenstion in ipynb file then converted it to py file and copied it here.

"This code is leaking memory somewhere" - what proof of that do you have exactly? Please be very specific. Also, about your edit; how you wrote the code doesn't matter, only how you run it does. Do you run it in a Jupyter notebook? Then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221451/how-to-deallocate-memory-from-an-object-in-jupyter-notebook . Or just run it as a normal Python script.

@ThierryLathuille Since Kernel was crashing on notebook again and again, I looked upon Task Manager for memory consumption. Then I noticed that memory was reaching 100% and then code crashes. And yes I am running in Jupyter Notebook.

As explained in the link in my comment, Jupyter keeps references to lots of variables you use, so they don't get actually deleted. Try the proposed solutions, or just run the code you posted here without Jupyter - does it work?

@ThierryLathuille It did worked when I ran it only as python script. But it still takes 3GB of ram which I would like to reduce.
